# How do you specify multiple browsers in autoprefixer using browserlist

Tags: webpack, autoprefixer

I just wanted to know how to specify multiple browsers in autoprefixer

So for instance I currently have

```
postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['ie >= 9'] }) ],
```

But if I wanted to specify also firefox greater than 20 and safari greater than 9.1 how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you pass in the various browsers specified as an array of strings to the query.

So to specify **firefox** greater than 20, **safari** greater than 9.1 and **IE** greater than 9:

```
postcss: [autoprefixer({ browsers: ['ie 10', 'firefox 20', 'safari 9.1' ] }) ],
```

This seems to be working... however the [docs](https://github.com/ai/browserslist) are a little vague on how multiple browser queries work as a string with autoprefixer

Here is some relevant parts of the browserlist docs:

- You can select browsers by passing a string. This library will use Can I Use data to return list of all matching versions.
- You can specify the versions by queries (case insensitive):
- Names are case insensitive: